# J2EE installation on Mac OSX

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I'm kinda stuck with compiling a Servlet in Eclipse on Mac OSX 10.10. Code doesn't matter here - it's a simple HelloWorld example. Point is, I need to install J2EE for this and I have a hard time figuring out how.

Now - I went to oracle's web page

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-7-downloads-1956236.html

and downloaded the .zip file. Turns out to be some kind of application server called Glassfish. I don't need this. I don't want this. (I wanna deploy my app on a Jetty) Whatever. But where's the J2EE?

In the documentation it reads

```
To Install the Software

The following procedure describes how to install the SDK distributions using the ZIP file.

Download the distribution file for your platform from the Java EE 7 SDK Downloads page.

Navigate to the directory where you downloaded the file.

Unzip the file.

Solaris, Linux, and Mac OS X systems:   unzip zip-file-name

Windows systems: Unzip using your favorite file compression utility.

The Java EE 7 SDK Update 1 or Java EE 7 Web Profile SDK Update 1 is extracted into a new glassfish4 directory under your current directory.
```

That's pretty much it: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/documentation/javaee7sdk-install-1957708.html

Yeah - the content looks like a bunch of examples, this glassfish-server-thingy, and some docs.

Now how do I get from here to Eclipse compiling an `HttpServlet`-class??? Googled for an hour by now - nothing really helped :(

Comment: You do it like you would compile any other class depending on a library: you download the library (i.e. in this case, the servlet api jar file), and you put that jar file in the build path of your project. Glassfish comes with this jar, Jetty comes with this jar, the Maven repository has this jar. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet

Comment: so you're telling me, that jetty will do the compiling and there's no way to have something like code completion, javadoc without using/installing jboss/galssfish/ whatever locally?

Comment: No. I didn't say that at all. I said that the servlet api is a jar file as any other library is, and that to be able to access classes of this API in your project, you must do the same thing as for any other library: download the jar file and add it to the build path of your eclipse project. Where to find this jar file? It comes with jetty, tomcat, glassfish or whatever container implementing the servlet api, or it can also be found in the Maven repository.

Comment: to all facing the same problem: eclipse offers a pretty easy solution:
you write your code and select "fix project setup" in the help toolbox that pops up when hovering your mouse over warnings or errors. it will offer you to add an javax.servlet.* jar
done :)
no need to download a jetty, glassfish or anything else

Comment: You still need to download one of them as otherwise you are going to have a very hard time actually running anything you compile.